# outputField error : <apex: outputField> is not dynamic binding?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I need to output a picklist value by using the tag outputField; however, I am getting the following error message:

```
An attempt was made to load the template for the example: Value for <apex: outputField> is not dynamic binding !. Please try editing your markup to correct the problem.
```

Component:

```
<apex:component access="global">
   <apex:attribute name="contact_et" type="Contact" description="Contact entry"/>
   <apex:outputField value="contact_et.EmailTitle__c"/>
</apex:component>
```

Email template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test" recipientType="Contact" language="en">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <c:component contact_et={!recipient}/>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It was missing "{!...}", solution as follows:

```
<apex:component access="global">
   <apex:attribute name="contact_et" type="Contact" description="Contact entry"/>
   <apex:outputField value="{!contact_et.EmailTitle__c}"/>
</apex:component>
```